# Adding New Address Directly from Shipping Address form Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I have a 'New Address' button on our checkout page, my issue is that the customer address is being saved after the order is placed, Can I have it saved after pressing save address button? I am thinking of using ajax to do that. Can someone point me in the right direction?

[image]

Comment: have you used any extension for shipping address?

Comment: No, I am using core magento feature